# how do I make two different media queries for mobile and website

Tags: css

I'm using the below media queries for website. As and when the window is expanded and contracted, it works fine. But for mobile phone, although on chrome dev tool's cell phone simulator, the layout looks perfect. But this same media queries breaks on my actual mobile phone(despite having the same design/layout for both mobile and web). How can I make two different media queries?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 10px) and (max-width: 319px) {
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
}

@media screen and (min-width: 641px) {
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
}

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) {
}
```

edit: iphone 6.
The reason I have so many break pints is because I'm using background image. When window size is made small, the image(with no background repeat) shows blank space at the bottom. To counter that problem, had to go with many breakpoints.

Comment: Can you provide some details about your phone? What is the resolution? Sometimes phones have bigger resolutions than PCs.

Comment: Strive to have one or two breakpoints and you'll end up with a more flexible style sheet.  You'll never please all the phones if you try to style to exact widths like this.

Comment: does your page have a viewport meta tag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Yes. has view port meta tag. See my edits

Comment: Set a min-width for your site so you can avoid the min-width 10px

Comment: On a side note, I would try `background-size: cover` on your background image. This would allow it to stretch and scale in the background without any white space. If you need to, also add `background-position: center center`

Answer (score 0):

Use max-width instead of min-width. Because i think all your media query represent when the screen resolution bigger than 320 678 etc and due to that only desktop query execute.